# Convert CEST/CET to UTC+0

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have my DateTimes in the format of `2021-01-23 20:05:03 CET` or `2021-04-18 23:34:27 CEST`, and want it to be converted back to UTC+0. The first will then be `2021-01-23 19:05:03` and the second would be `2021-04-18 21:34:27`.

I have a function to make it from UTC+0 to CEST/CET,  but how can I make it the other way?

**Function**

```php
function convertTimeZone($strDateTime, $sourceTimeZone, $targetTimeZone){
    return date_create($strDateTime, new DateTimeZone($sourceTimeZone))
      ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($targetTimeZone))
      ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
  }
```

**EDIT**

So I tried to implement the times but without the CEST/CET, and then getting that information with the date() function, and thereby subtracting 1 or 2 hours from the times. Would this be a hack way to do this? Note: location is set to `Europe/Copenhagen` because it's where the time should be taken from (CET/CEST).

```php
function convertCESTorCET($DateTime){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
    if (strpos(date('T'), 'CET') !== false) {
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime)-3600);
    }
    if (strpos(date('T'), 'CEST') !== false) {
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime)-(3600*2));
    }
    return $time;
}
```

The above doesn't work I see.. since the CET/CEST isn't looking at the date itself, but a the current CET/CEST. The function  have to look at the date and that way determine if it should be CEST/CET.

**Made this and it works:**

```php
function convertCESTorCET($DateTime){
    // Create two timezone objects
    $dateTimeZoneUTC0= new DateTimeZone('Atlantic/Reykjavik');
    $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen');

    // Create two DateTime objects that will contain the same Unix timestamp, but
    // have different timezones attached to them.
    $dateTimeUTC = new DateTime($DateTime, $dateTimeZoneUTC0);
    $dateTimeCEST_CET = new DateTime($DateTime, $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET);

    // Calculate the GMT offset for the date/time contained in the $dateTimeUTC
    // object, but using the timezone rules as defined for Denmark
    // ($dateTimeCEST_CET).
    $timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET->getOffset($dateTimeUTC);

    return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime($DateTime)-$timeOffset));
}
```

Comment: Tried to make a function which does something like this, is this a good enough way to do this?

Comment: I found a error in my new function (made a edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code takes the difference between a country with UTC0 and the country with CEST/CET, and return the difference between these two subtracted from the `$DateTime`.

```php
function convertCESTorCET($DateTime){
    // Create two timezone objects
    $dateTimeZoneUTC0= new DateTimeZone('Atlantic/Reykjavik');
    $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen');

    // Create two DateTime objects that will contain the same Unix timestamp, but
    // have different timezones attached to them.
    $dateTimeUTC = new DateTime($DateTime, $dateTimeZoneUTC0);
    $dateTimeCEST_CET = new DateTime($DateTime, $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET);

    // Calculate the GMT offset for the date/time contained in the $dateTimeUTC
    // object, but using the timezone rules as defined for Denmark
    // ($dateTimeCEST_CET).
    $timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneCEST_CET->getOffset($dateTimeUTC);

    return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime($DateTime)-$timeOffset));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new date using your timestamp.

```
let dated = new Date(yourDateValue);
const finalDateString = dated.toUTCString();
console.log(finalDateString);
```

This might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for PHP: create DateTime and set the time zone to UTC.

**example 1**

```
$cet = "2021-01-23 20:05:03 CET";

$utcCET = date_create($cet)->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $utcCET->format('c');
//2021-01-23T19:05:03+00:00
```

**example 2**

```
$cest = "2021-04-18 23:34:27 CEST"; 

$utcCEST = date_create($cest)->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $utcCEST->format('c');
//2021-04-18T21:34:27+00:00
```